# Adjusting spacing added by a new command

Tags: fonts, spacing

I am writing a document in which I am using a font different form the LaTeX default. I am using EB Garamond, among the features of which is oldstyle lowercase numbers. I am fine with this feature, and I would like almost all of the numbers present in the document to be in this format.

However, not all numbers. I am numbering some paragraphs by prefacing them thus: **§ [number].---**[text] (e.g. **§ 1.---**[text].). I would prefer if the number there were "uppercase," which EB Garamond does allow through the font features `tnum` and `lnum`.

Since I will be using the aforementioned numbering notation often, I thought that defining a new command would be most efficient; a new command which would apply the above font feature to the number. I named the command `\num`:

```
\newcommand{\num}[1]{
    {\addfontfeatures{RawFeature={+tnum, +lnum}}#1}.
}
```

I am a total novice when it comes to creating new commands; this one succeded, however, though not entirely in the way I wanted. The new command `\num` effectively changed the numeral to uppercase (see the second line of the text in the attached image), it introduced empty space to the left and right of the number (use the added red lines to compare spacing to the other lines).

Perhaps not the best idea, but I thought about adding `\(` and `\)` to both sides; and it removed the spacing as I wished, but it changed the font of the number back to default (see line three in the attached image).

**My question:** What should I add to or change in the definition of the new command, or anywhere in the document, to remove the strange spacing around the numeral *and* retain the font of the number, EB Garamond?

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}

\newcommand{\num}[1]{
    {\addfontfeatures{RawFeature={+tnum, +lnum}}#1}.
}

\begin{document}

§ 5.---To the left is a lowercase, oldstyle Garamond 5.

§ \num{5}---To the left is an "uppercase" Garamond 5. NB the spacing with the command.

§ \(\num{5}\)---As before, but the attempt to remove the spacing changed the font of the 5.

The above are some visual examples. Oldstyle lowercase numerals: 1234567890.

\end{document}
```

And the image, with red lines added to highlight the strange spacing I would do away with:

[image: The product of the MWE.]

Comment: you defined `\newcommand{\num}[1]{   {\addfontfeatures{RawFeature={+tnum, +lnum}}#1}. }` so adds a space at start and end, you intended `\newcommand{\num}[1]{{\addfontfeatures{RawFeature={+tnum, +lnum}}#1}.}`

Comment: Thank you! I knew it had to be some stupid mistake...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment by David Carlisle, the mistake was simple. Spaces were added before and after because the new command was defined like so:

```
\newcommand{\num}[1]{
    {\addfontfeatures{RawFeature={+tnum, +lnum}}#1}.
}
```

When it should have been:

```
\newcommand{\num}[1]{{\addfontfeatures{RawFeature={+tnum, +lnum}}#1}.}
```

The way I first wrote the command added the space before and after. The latter way does not add any unwanted spacing. Thanks again to Mr. Carlisle for his answer!